# Help with c++ template templates

Tags: c++, templates, template-templates

Ok, so I wrote an stl-like algorithm called `cartesian_product`. For those who don't know, the cartesian product is every possible pair of elements from two sets. So the cartesian product of `{1, 2, 3}` and `{10, 20, 30}` is

`{(1,10), (1,20), (1,30), (2,10), (2,20), (2,30), (3,10), (3,20), (3,30)}`

So the function looks like

```
template <typename InIt1, typename InIt2, typename OutIt>
void
cartesian_product(InIt1 first1, InIt1 last1, InIt2 first2, InIt2 last2, OutIt out)
{
    for (; first1 != last1; ++first1)
        for (InIt2 it = first2; it != last2; ++it)
            *out++ = std::make_pair(*first1, *it);
}
```

There aren't template typedefs, so I made a traits class to hold the type that
the output iterator is from:

```
template <typename ObjA, typename ObjB, template <typename> class Container>
struct cartesian_product_traits
{
    typedef Container<std::pair<ObjA, ObjB> > type;
};
```

So then I can say:

```
typedef cartesian_product_traits<int, int, std::vector>::type IntPairList;
IntPairList my_list;
cartesian_product(v1.begin(), v1.end(), 
                  v2.begin(), v2.end(),
                  std::back_inserter(my_list);
```

but this doesn't seem to compile. I get a nice error:

```
error C3201: the template parameter list for class template 'std::vector' does not match the template parameter list for template parameter 'Container'
```

So I'm stumped. How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The template parameter list for vector isn't just one element, it takes two:

```
template < class T, class Allocator = allocator<T> > class vector
```

so in order to accept vector, you need to have a template template parameter with two blanks:

```
template <typename ObjA, typename ObjB, template <typename, typename> class Container>
struct cartesian_product_traits
```

**Edited:** cut some advice, misread your code.

The way to do this properly would be to use a variadic macro on the template template parameter:

```
template <typename ObjA, typename ObjB, template <typename ...> class Container>
struct cartesian_product_traits
```

But that's far away from being a standard. If it were my code, I'd probably just have the consumers pound out the full template:

```
std::vector< std::pair<int, int> >
```

is shorter than

```
cartesian_product_traits<int, int, vector>
```

and the latter would only help if the definition for a Cartesian product changed.

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector`'s template is actually quite complex (with optional template parameters for allocators &c) -- and other containers in the stdlib aren't any simpler either. In your shoes, I'd make the third parameter of `cartesian_product_traits` into a plain `typename PairsContainer` and depend on the caller to go to the small trouble of passing it as a suitable container of pairs.