# Find the combination of two vector arrays which sums to maximum of all the other combinations in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

To find the maximum sum pair where one element is taken from one vector array and other element from second vector array .I found this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546701/how-to-get-combination-of-two-array-vector-by-stl-algorithm#) but this fails when the size of the v1 and v2 both become 100000 as the output array size exceeds the limit and abort is called.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
typedef int T;
struct Fctor
{
    typedef std::vector<T>::iterator Iterator;
    Iterator it1, it2, begin, end;
    Fctor(Iterator begin1, Iterator end1, Iterator begin2)
    {
        begin = begin1;
        end = end1;
        it1 = begin1;
        it2 = begin2;
    }
    T operator()()
    {
        // T result = f(*it1, *it2);
        T result = (*it1) * (*it2);
        if(++it1 != end) return result;
        it1 = begin;
        ++it2;
        return result;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<T> v1; v1.push_back(1); v1.push_back(2);
    std::vector<T> v2; v2.push_back(3); v2.push_back(4); v2.push_back(5);
    std::vector<T> result(v1.size() * v2.size());
    Fctor fctor(v2.begin(), v2.end(), v1.begin());
    generate(result.begin(), result.end(), fctor);
    std::copy(result.begin(), result.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<T>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
    // => 3 4 5 6 8 10
}
```

Comment: I've got some bad news. Looks like your keyboard is broken, and the `TAB` key does not work reliably. Because of the lack of logical indentation, the shown code is mostly unreadable. You should get your keyboard replaced, and rewrite your code with clear, logical indentation, so that other people can actually read it.

Comment: Isn't the answer just the maximum element from each vector? You don't need to generate all possible pairs.

Comment: Is there a way to check all the combinations of both the vectors in less than o(n^2) time(Any inbuilt function or so.)

Comment: There are NxM combinations so checking all combinations is going to be NxM. Why do you need all combinations? The max sum pair can be found in linear time (scan for max value of each vector).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum sum pair is just the sum of the largest value from each vector. You don't need to generate all combinations or a temporary vector. Here is a very simple O(n) implementation using a standard library algorithm.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1{ 1,2 };
    std::vector<int> v2{ 3,4,5 };

    int max1 = *std::max_element(v1.begin(), v1.end());
    int max2 = *std::max_element(v2.begin(), v2.end());

    std::cout << "max sum = " << (max1 + max2) << '\n';
}

// max sum = 7
```